# App crashes on HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget) when attempting to send to JSON

Tags: java, android, json, httpclient

I am trying to get `JSONObject` from Android app but crash on
`response = httpclient.execute(httpget)` and raise an exception.

I think that problem is url encoding but I am not sure. If I not encode URL, app crash a few lines above on `httpget = new HttpGet(encodeURL)`.

URL that I pass is: http://api.elpais.com/ws/LoteriaNavidadPremiados?n=99999

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;

public class Json {

    public Json(){

    }

    public static JSONObject getJson(String url) {

    String encodeUrl = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    HttpGet httpget;

    // Encode URL. If not, HttpGet will crash
    try {
        encodeUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
        //encodeUrl = encodeUrl.replaceAll("%3F", "?"); // I tried replacing this but does not work
        //encodeUrl = encodeUrl.replaceAll("%3D", "=");  //

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("LOG_EXCEPTION", "Unsuported Encoding Exception");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // HTTP
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // for port 80
        // requests!
        httpget = new HttpGet(encodeUrl);
        // HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                    Log.d("LOG", "THIS CODE I SEE in LOGCAT");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // HERE CRASH
                    Log.d("LOG", "THIS CODE I DO NOT SEE in LOGCAT");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.d("LOG_EXCEPTION", "IOException");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        Log.d("LOG_EXCEPTION", "URL no valida");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // return null;
        Log.d("LOG_EXCEPTION", "Exception");
    }

    // Read response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("LOG_EXCEPTION", "Reader response to string");
        // return null;
    }

    // Convert string to object
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // return null;
    }
    return jsonObject;

}

}
```

---

and Log:

```
12-01 11:04:01.336: D/(1631): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established                                    0xb8d029d0, tid 1631
12-01 11:04:05.866: D/LOG(1631): http%3A%2F%2Fapi.elpais.com%2Fws%2FLoteriaNavidadPremiados?n=99999
12-01 11:04:05.866: D/LOG(1631): httpget work fine
12-01 11:04:06.176: D/LOG_EXCEPTION(1631): Exception
12-01 11:04:06.176: D/LOG_EXCEPTION(1631): Reader response to string
12-01 11:04:06.176: D/AndroidRuntime(1631): Shutting down VM
12-01 11:04:06.186: W/dalvikvm(1631): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a5bb90)
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631): Process: com.example.loterianavidad, PID:    1631
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at com.example.loterianavidad.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:86)
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at     android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-01 11:04:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

The MainActivity relevant code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Accediendo a la base de datos...";
    JSONObject j = Json.getJson("http://api.elpais.com/ws/LoteriaNavidadPremiados?n=99999");
    Log.d("LOG", j.toString()); // HERE is LINE 87
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
    String prem = "hola";
```

Comment: problem is inside `onClick` method in `MainActivity` line `87` please share relevant part of code to get more help

Comment: there, I only instantiate the object. 
86. JSONObject j = json.getJson("http://api.elpais.com/ws/LoteriaNavidadPremiados?n=99999");
87. Log.d("LOG", j.toString()); // to check if the object is correct

Comment: use `JSONObject j = Json.getJson("api.elpais.com/ws/LoteriaNavidadPremiados?n=99999");` instead of small `s` in class name because `getJson` method is `static` so you can access it without creating instance of Json class

Comment: Okay, do it. But the problem is not in MainActivity. Is in this class. 

Log.d("LOG", "THIS CODE I SEE in LOGCAT");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // HERE CRASH
Log.d("LOG", "THIS CODE I DO NOT SEE in LOGCAT");

Comment: are you able to see `Log.d("LOG_EXCEPTION", "Unsuported Encoding Exception");` line in logcat ? if yes then share full logcat results or MainActivity code

Comment: Encoding also works fine. Does not raise any exception.

Comment: see my answer just encode parameters inside of url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are encoding whole url with parameters so just encode parameter then append to url before passing to `HttpGet` constructor as:

```
String str_url="99999";
encodeUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
String final_url="http://api.elpais.com/ws/LoteriaNavidadPremiados?n="+encodeUrl;
```

Comment: Good! thank you very much. But unfortunately I have even a problem. One sec.

Comment: @IkerOcioZuazo : what problem ?

Comment: Finally I have two problems. First one is that if I encode parameters in URL "http://api.elpais.com/ws/LoteriaNavidadPremiados?n%3D99999" like this, json that I recieve is busqueda={"error":1}, but if you get request from plain URL (replacing "%3D" with "="), json that I recieve is busqueda={"numero":99999,"premio":0,"timestamp":1356190680,"status":2,"error":0}.
 I think that will be better create another question.

Comment: @IkerOcioZuazo : my mistake just encode value instead of parameters follow this syntax :: www.example.com/test/name= URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")+"second_param="+URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")

Comment: Thanks. The  second  LAST problem...

The "result" variable, return a String: example={"key":value,"key2":value2}... Ok. Then I create JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result) and If I look with logcat something like Log.d("LOG", jsonObject.toString()); logcat raise  another NullPointerException. Any idea?

Comment: Solved. JSONObject constructor(String) only admit {"key":value, "key2": value} and not example={"key":value, "key2": value} as a string

Answer (score 0):

your app is crashing on line number `87` in MAINACTIVITY

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 12-01 10:25:08.546: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): at com.example.loterianavidad.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)
```

because you're using `onclicklistener` on a button which does not exist in the referred XML view of MAINACTIVITY

Comment: That button works correct. If I remove line number 87 in MAIN 87 Log.d("LOG", j.toString()) the code of under, works fine.